# Data visibility in Public blockchain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, transactions, privacy

When a data is uploaded by an  user to blockchain, it is distributed to multiple nodes. Since transparency is maintained, everyone can see it. is my data secured if I want no-one to see the content?
Please explain me the working of how other nodes, though have the copy, can't see the original data.

Answer (score 1):

It is optimized for persistant processes and storage. It does this through transparency.

You should assume everyone can see everything. They can.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload data to the public and transparent blockchain, the content is visible to anyone who has access to the blockchain explorer or the data stored in the blocks.

If you want to secure the content of your data and keep it private, you might consider to encrypt the data before uploading it to the blockchain. But still, there are risks.